# Add current revision number of Hiberante Envers in Hibernate Search index

Tags: hibernate-search, hibernate-envers

I am using Hibernate Envers 5.6 and would like to use Hibernate Search 6.x. I would also like to use Hibernate Search projection queries to load data fast out of the index.

But I need to be revision save. If the index and the database are out of sync it would be enough for me to read the Hibernate Envers revision number right out of the Hibernate Search projection.

Is there any mechanism which already does that in a performant way?

Thank you for ideas

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no built-in support for this. You will have to implement it yourself.

You'll probably need a `TypeBridge` that adds a `version` field to your document, but I'm not sure how you can get the current revision when indexing (or even *if* you can do it). You can [access the ORM session from the bridge](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-bridge-typebridge-access-orm), but beyond that I couldn't say. Maybe check the Envers documentation.

That beind said, when querying you will need to check the current revision, which means retrieving it from the database, which means you will still hit the database. So I'm not sure how much you will gain from this "optimization".

I would personally only bother with such optimizations when I *don't* absolutely need the latest version of the data, for non-critical features involving many hits, such as displaying search results on a map.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I tried it with a custom TypeBridge since the Hibernate session is enough in order to create Hibernate Envers queries. But I had no luck, the revision number is not generated yet when Hibernate Search triggers the event based indexing. I will perform the indexing explicitely after transaction completion.